# Is there a way to overwrite values of a dataframe to another when there is no key between the two dataframes, in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an two dataframes A and B. A is the original one but has some incorrect values. Dataframe B has only the values columns and has the correct values. Is there a way I can overwrite the values in A by those in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the values in `df_a` with those in `df_b` with:

```
df_a[df_b.columns] = df_b
```

For example:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5, 4)))    # df_a is 4 columns of ones
df_b = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 2)))   # df_b in 2 columns of zeros

df_a[df_b.columns] = df_b

df_a
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

---

You can also use `update` method, but it will only update values in `df_a` where a corresponding value in `df_b` is not `NaN` (if a value in `df_b` is `NaN`, the value in `df_a` will not be updated):

```
df_a.update(df_b)
```

Comment: `7,000` looked so cool but upvoted anyway `:)`

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes, it was bound to happen at some point :) Thanks!